# UILocalNotification not firing properly on iPhone when app not foregrounded

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

UPDATE - a warning to anyone with similar symptoms... check Do Not Disturb is not active!

I finally paid to get an app I was working on running on my iPhone instead of on the simulator.

Having done so I've spotted a strange behaviour with regards to the UILocalNotifications that I create, which are set to use the default sound UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName, and the default timezone ([NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]).

If the app is foregrounded then the local notification fires on time and I receive it within

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

and I create an alert view to display it.

If however I lock my phone just before a notification is expected then nothing appears on the screen, but when I press the home button to show the lock screen I can see my app's notification in the notification centre on the lock screen. No sound was played, but then again the phone didn't wake up to show the notification properly.

If however I just press the home button so the app is put in the background leaving me looking at the springboard apps then I don't see any notifications whatsoever, and again no sound is heard.

On the simulator the same code correctly fires the notification banner when looking at the app icons in the spring board, although I've never been able to hear any sounds for the notification. But as the simulator doesn't let you configure the notification centre for apps I always presumed it was perhaps set to not allow sounds. On my device sounds for this apps notifications are enabled, and i've tried it with banner and alert modes, with no joy. Very frustrating.

Has anyone experienced this, or have an idea what could be going on?

Comment: You've checked that you have banners/etc enabled for your app in the device's settings?

Comment: Yes I checked banner, and alert, sounds etc... in the end as I've said below it's my tiredness and my phone's tiredness... Do Not Disturb was causing what I was seeing (and not hearing!)

Answer (score 3):

Oh the irony of this answer.. think it's time to go to bed. My iPhone thinks that too for nearly 3 hours now... My question happily describes Do Not Disturbs behaviour, which was active.. Sorry to waste everyones time!!

Comment: Didn't waste anyones time.  Same thing happened to me today and this is the first link that comes up in a google search.